# Reading data from text file to postgres with python

Tags: python, postgresql, file, psycopg2

I can read the content of a test file `test.plt` in the root directory into a `postgres`  table `tempo` using this script:

```
$cat test.plt
Geolife trajectory
WGS 84
Altitude is in Feet
Reserved 3
0,2,255,My Track,0,0,2,8421376
0
39.9756783,116.3308383,0,131.2,39717.4473148148,2008-09-26,10:44:08
39.9756649,116.3308749,0,131.2,39717.4473842593,2008-09-26,10:44:14
39.97564,116.3308749,0,131.2,39717.4474189815,2008-09-26,10:44:17
39.9756533,116.3308583,0,131.2,39717.4474537037,2008-09-26,10:44:20
39.9756316,116.3308299,0,131.2,39717.4474884259,2008-09-26,10:44:23
39.9753166,116.3306299,0,131.2,39717.4480324074,2008-09-26,10:45:10
39.9753566,116.3305916,0,131.2,39717.4480671296,2008-09-26,10:45:13
39.9753516,116.3305249,0,131.2,39717.4481018518,2008-09-26,10:45:16
```

Python script:

```
import psycopg2
from config import config
import os
import glob

query = "INSERT INTO tempo (lat, lon, flag, alt, passeddate, gpsdate, gpstime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

path = '~/Desktop/Data/'

conn = None
try:
    #read the connection parameters
    params = config()
    # connect to the PostgreSQL server
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # INSERRT data to the database
    with open('test.plt') as file:
        file_content = file.readlines()[6:]
        values = [line.strip().split(',') for line in file_content]
        cur.executemany(query, values)

    cur.close()
        # commit the changes
    conn.commit()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Results:

```
postgres=> SELECT * FROM tempo;
 id |    lat     |     lon     | flag |  alt  |    passeddate    |  gpsdate   | gpstime  
----+------------+-------------+------+-------+------------------+------------+----------
    | 39.9756783 | 116.3308383 |    0 | 131.2 | 39717.4473148148 | 2008-09-26 | 10:44:08
    | 39.9756649 | 116.3308749 |    0 | 131.2 | 39717.4473842593 | 2008-09-26 | 10:44:14
    |   39.97564 | 116.3308749 |    0 | 131.2 | 39717.4474189815 | 2008-09-26 | 10:44:17
    | 39.9756533 | 116.3308583 |    0 | 131.2 | 39717.4474537037 | 2008-09-26 | 10:44:20
    | 39.9756316 | 116.3308299 |    0 | 131.2 | 39717.4474884259 | 2008-09-26 | 10:44:23
    | 39.9753166 | 116.3306299 |    0 | 131.2 | 39717.4480324074 | 2008-09-26 | 10:45:10
    | 39.9753566 | 116.3305916 |    0 | 131.2 | 39717.4480671296 | 2008-09-26 | 10:45:13
    | 39.9753516 | 116.3305249 |    0 | 131.2 | 39717.4481018518 | 2008-09-26 | 10:45:16
(8 rows)
```

I can also get the names of all files in all sub-directories with the `.plt` extension (stripping the `.plt` ext ) by replacing the insert statement in the python script with:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".plt"):
                print(file.strip('.plt'))
```

Output:

```
20081210001529
20081113121334
20081205143505
20081029234123
20081202145929
20081204142253
20081111234235
20081118003844
20081105110052
20081023055305
```

As you can see, files are named in figures. The goal is to take each file name, insert it into the `id` field of the `tempo`table, then its contents into the rest of columns. Repeating this for each in file in all sub-directories.

1. How do I modify my code so that the filename(`e.g. 20081210001529`) is added to the insert query (get inserted to the table)

Using the code below, with the intent to read data from all files in sub-directories (i.e. having listed all file in code above) gives error with only the first file in the first sub-directory, listed.

```
query = "INSERT INTO tempo (lat, lon, flag, alt, passeddate, gpsdate, gpstime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

path = '~/Desktop/Data/'
#Establish connection to postgres
conn = None
try:
    #read the connection parameters
    params = config()
    # connect to the PostgreSQL server
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".plt"):
                f = open(file, 'r')
                content = f.readlines()[6:]
                values = [lines.strip().split(',') for line in content]
                cur.executemany(query, values)

    cur.close()
        # commit the changes
    conn.commit()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20081210001529.plt'
```

I would appreciate your help on this task.

Answer (score 0):

`file` just holds the filename, you need to create a full path (`os.path.join`).

I just put you code into 2 functions (first one to find all plt files, second one to insert each file's contents) that makes error handling easier:

```
def findFiles(rootDir):
    pltFiles = []
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
        for x in files:
            if x.endswith(".plt"):
                pltFiles.append(os.path.join(path, x))  # create full path!
    return pltFiles

def insert(pltFilePath):
    query = "INSERT INTO tempo (lat, lon, flag, alt, passeddate, gpsdate, gpstime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    f = open(file, 'r')
    content = f.readlines()[6:]
    values = [lines.strip().split(',') for line in content]
    status = False
    try:
        cur.executemany(query, values)
        status = True
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
    return status


path = '/tmp/data'
pltFiles = findFiles(path)

if not pltFiles:
    print("No plt files found!")

for pltFile in pltFiles:
    print("Processing: %s" % pltFile)
    res = insert(pltFile)
    # res holds true or false, so you could rename, move or delete the file:
    #if res:
    #   os.remove(fullPath)
```